# Is there any decidable problem that is NOT NP-HARD?

Tags: computational-complexity

Is there a proof that there exists a decidable problem that is NOT NP-HARD??

Answer (score 3):

Very simple answer:

Since you need one $x \in A$, and one $x \not \in A$ for a polynomial time reduction, $A = \emptyset$ cannot be a hard language for NP.

Comment: haha... wonderful.. thnx

Comment: and under $P=NP$ only $\emptyset$ and $A^{\ast}$ are not NP-hard under polynomial time reductions.

Comment: @sdcvvc, not NP-hard you mean.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction.